# Accessing Private Folder With PHP

Tags: php

I am using an Apache web server.  I have two folder httpd.www and httpd.private.  My web pages reside in the www folder and are accessible from a browser.

Files stored in the private folder are not available through a browser.

I have some files in the private folder that I want to serve on my webpage through a link.  I can't find a way to access it though.

I have tried various methods to get to the root of the www then up a level to httpd.private, but nothing seems to work.  I have done this before but can't remember how.

`<source src="/../private/videos/About_Me.mp4" type="video/mp4">`

`<source src="../../private/videos/About_Me.mp4" type="video/mp4">`

Comment: This does not have anything to do with php. If you intend on this file being available to the public, move it to the www folder.

Comment: I don't want it available to the public - I want it available to the web server

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood. This looks like the video file is in an html tag. Meaning that if someone accessed the page this tag was on, they should be able to see the video. If that is the case, the video does have to be publicly available somehow. Moving it to a place that can be accessed by the browser is the simplest way. Otherwise you would need an htaccess rule (I think) or some kind of script that proxies the file from the inaccessible part of the filesystem to something that is accessible to the browser.